# Which "Earth" is seen in "Crossroads, Part II"?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

At the very end of "Crossroads, Part II", after Starbuck comes back, we see "Earth". At the time, we assume that this is the same "Earth" she has just been speaking about. However, at the end of the series finale "Daybreak", the fleet arrives at a second planet they also call "Earth". This corresponds to the planet we call home IRL. Let's call them Earth 1 and Earth 2.

I always assumed that the "Earth" we saw in "Crossroads, Part II" was still "Earth 1". However, in the episode, one can clearly make out continents corresponding to our real Earth, for example the continent of North America. As "Earth 2" corresponds to our real-life Earth, it presumably has the same continents.

Does this mean that Earth 1 and Earth 2 are geographically the same? Or does it mean that the planet we saw in "Crossroads, Part II" is actually "Earth 2"?

I'm interested in any in-universe or out-of-universe (e.g. interviews etc) explanations.